# How to train a model to classify input to one or more classes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, text-classification

I use this sample code to train a model to classify a random number into a one of 10 classes

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

samples_number = 1000
features_number = 5
output_classes_number = 10
x_train = np.random.random((samples_number, features_number))
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(output_classes_number, size=(samples_number, 1)), num_classes=output_classes_number)

model = Sequential()
# Dense(64) is a fully-connected layer with 64 hidden units.
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=features_number))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          epochs=1000,
          batch_size=128)
```

In this sample, a sample value of `x_train[0]` is

```
[0.54071786 0.31048455 0.87843899 0.88947151 0.89052953]
```

and a sample output of `y_train[0]` is

```
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
```

which means that the `x_train[0]` values map to the `7th` feature.

In this online sample sample code, there's only **one** matched class for each input.

---

How can I change my code to train 5 features into one or more than class in the same time?

For example, a possible `y_train[z]` value may be `[0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your final activation function to `sigmoid` and you will get the probability per class, and so it allows multi-label classification.

Naturally, you will need labels that reflect this new task, which you don't seem to have at the moment.

Full example:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras

x_train = np.random.random((1000, 4))
y_train = np.random.randint(0, 2, (1000, 4))
```

Multi-label targets:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=4))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='sgd')

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          epochs=10,
          batch_size=16)
```

```
model.predict(x_train)
```

Probabilities per class:

```
array([[0.48028257, 0.48918256, 0.4759362 , 0.51707023],
       [0.460468  , 0.50321233, 0.5157731 , 0.51490146],
       [0.5088656 , 0.50617874, 0.47503173, 0.5145618 ],
       ...,
       [0.452385  , 0.48947614, 0.47086555, 0.51236445],
       [0.48170012, 0.475545  , 0.48153797, 0.49793705],
       [0.47959277, 0.5056894 , 0.45207116, 0.50883204]], dtype=float32)
```

If it was done with `softmax`, these probabilities would sum up to 1, because it predicts only one category:

```
array([[0.2694298 , 0.21779475, 0.23155291, 0.28122255],
       [0.28732255, 0.24838863, 0.23328216, 0.23100664],
       [0.28733823, 0.24516277, 0.23259555, 0.23490342],
       ...,
       [0.28732476, 0.21751696, 0.24203528, 0.253123  ],
       [0.27158916, 0.26262963, 0.22158018, 0.244201  ],
       [0.27889836, 0.25647762, 0.20330393, 0.2613201 ]], dtype=float32)
```